# I want to be alerted when one of a set of URLs appears on Twitter

Tags: twitter

There are a set of articles at various bits of the internet that I either wrote or that are linking to something I wrote.

I'll like either be able to get an alert when one of these appears on Twitter, or be able to put a set of URLs into a search bar and have tweets that references *any* of the URLs.

I've got a list of about 20 or 30, and I expect that this might grow over the years.

Answer (score 3):

From my testing, searching for `"domain1.com/article1" OR "domain2.org/article2" OR "domain3.net/article3"` (including quotes, uppercase *OR*) seems to work.

Twitter appears to expand shortened URLs within tweets so you needn’t worry about handling those cases.

You should then be able to setup an [**If-This-Then-That**](https://ift.tt/) Applet to send you an alert through the medium of your choice (email, SMS, in-app notification…) whenever a new tweet matches your criterion.

[image: IFTTT: New Tweet From Search]

Twitter’s [Help Document](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577) doesn’t specify whether there is a character limit on searches, but I imagine sooner or later you’ll need to split up your query. In the meantime, you may omit any prefix and subdomain, and only retain the parts that uniquely identify your pages.

It’s worth mentioning that starting sometime in December 2016, you can no longer insert `TweetEmbedCode` into emails sent to an iCloud address.

Comment: That's the sort of thing that I should have been able to work out on my own, but somehow failed to. I'll have a quick test.

Comment: Okay, it appears that this approah requires spliting the URLs into twos and threes. which gets tiresome fast... upvoting anyway.

Comment: You can use MyTweetAlerts.com but it is paid service.